# How to do Node.js path aliases?

Tags: node.js, webpack, alias, webpack-dev-server, nodemon

I am using Webpack in order to build my Node.js backend project.
In my Webpack config I have aliases, like this:

```
alias: {
  '@': resolvePath('src'),
  '@app': resolvePath('src/app'),
},
```

When I build the app for production, those aliases are working, since Webpack converts them to the their real paths on the created bundle.

However I ran nodemon in order to develop the API. And nodemon is not related to the webpack bundle or the devserver.
Therefore this is getting error (obviously):

```
let myService = require('@services/my-service');
```

I want to ask how to run those aliases using Webpack config OR allow kind of aliases using the nodemon server before a bundle was created - in dev mod.

Comment: You should use another library to handle the aliase in your prod environment, look at this one maybe : https://www.npmjs.com/package/module-alias